# Angular7: Show placeholder image on loading

Tags: angular

show placeholder image before imnage loads in angular 2+

```html
<div *ngFor="let key of news>
    <img *ngIf="key.default_photo.img_path" class="img-fluid w-100" 
   [src]="api/uploads/key.default_photo.img_path"  alt="{{key.news_title}}">
</div>
```

Comment: It's in spanish, but I like https://medium.com/mycodebad/preloading-de-im%C3%A1genes-con-angular-399441afa461

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Image object along with the onload event, which triggers when the image is loaded by the browser

```js
  let imgIsLoaded = false;
  const img = new Image(250, 250);
  img.src = 'mypath.jpg';
  img.onload(() => {
   imgIsLoaded = true;
  });
```

```css
img.isLoading {
  background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150)
}
```

```html
<img src="mypath.jpg" [class.isLoading]="!imgIsLoaded">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is to define `background-image: url-of-placeholder-image` in CSS. 
The placeholder image should be small enough to load fast. You can even define the placeholder image as base64 encoded string directly in CSS. [See here - CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/)

But most likely you will have issues with different image sizes. It would be great if you knew the image dimensions beforehand. Otherwise the page might "jump" when image of various size will be displayed.